# Foreign Key Failing in SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to create a relationship between three tables but it seems to be failing for some reason that is not specified. When I created a one to one relation it worked, many to one it worked too, but one too many is failing. Here is my layout in a nutshell:

Table 1 has two fields, `name` which is some text and `linkId` which is a non-unique integer.

Table 3 has two fields, `stat` which is text and `statId` which is a non-unique integer.

Table 2 is the linking table, it has two fields `linkId` and `statId` which are both unique and both reference the respective value from tables 1 and 3.

So some test data:

Table 1:

```
name   linkId
"Test 1"   1
"Test 2"   1
"Test 3"   1
"Test 4"   1
"Test 5"   1
```

Table 3:

```
stat linkId
"strength" 1
"intelligence" 1
"dexterity" 1
```

Table 2:

```
linkId statId
1         1
```

Why is this failing? Shouldn't the `1`s in table 2 reference the `1`s in the other tables? Note that if I make the table 1 field `linkId` unique then it works, but this is not how I want it to work.

Comment: Please clarify what "Foriegn Key Failing" means?  Are you getting an exception, invalid query results, etc?

Comment: It simply says `Foreign Key Mismatch` when I try to enter the data in Table 2. I am using SqLiteStudio if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SQLITE does not support a foreign key where the reference table column is non unique. I changed my table layout a bit and it works now.